# Файл сервер на golang

Tags: golang

Использовал этот код для статических файлов:

```
func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./files")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil)
}
```

Потом появилась необходимость расширить приложение. Добавил роутинг:

```
package main
import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux" 
    "fmt"
)

func main() { 
  router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
  router.HandleFunc("/", Index)   
  router.HandleFunc("/files/", FileServer)

  http.ListenAndServe(":5000", router)
} 

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Привет. Это главная страница")
}  

func FileServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.FileServer(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./files"))
}
```

---

Но статические файлы не грузятся. Нужно, чтобы по ссылке `site/files/css/my.css` грузился соответственный файл.

Как мне и роутинг сделать, и файл-сервер чтоб был?

---

```
Ответ
    Спасибо D-side.

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    s := http.StripPrefix("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./files/"))) 
    router.HandleFunc("/", Index)
    router.PathPrefix("/files/").Handler(s)
    http.Handle("/", router)
    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Сделать нормально роутинг.**

Сейчас URL вида `/files/example.txt` не проходит ни по одному из правил, а точнее, не совпадает с `/files/`.

Вам нужно не "точное совпадение", а префикс в этом случае. [Функция `PathPrefix`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Route.PathPrefix) занимается как раз этим.

***Дисклеймер:** я не работал с Go вообще. То, что я это нашёл почти мгновенно, говорит о том, что вы не прикладывали усилий, чтобы найти решение самостоятельно.*

Comment: Я пробовал вариант router.Handle("/files/{path}", http.StripPrefix("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./files"))))   , но он тоже не работает

Comment: А можете эту строчку кода написать?, а то я перепробывал- не работает

Comment: @TwoRS с синтаксисом Go незнаком. Посмотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834278/serving-static-content-with-a-root-url-with-the-gorilla-toolkit).

Comment: Спасибо. 
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    s := http.StripPrefix("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./files/"))) 
    router.HandleFunc("/", Index)
    router.PathPrefix("/files/").Handler(s)
    http.Handle("/", router)
    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil)